# How can I create a game in RMVX without battle scenes?

Tags: rpg-maker-vx

I want to create a story-like game which depends on situations based on your decisions. I don't want to have "battle scenes" in my game; can I disregard the EXP/HP stuffs to create my own game?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes you can, although you will need ruby scripting to achieve that kind of modification.
Probably the are some community resources you could use to achieve it. Check [here](http://www.rpgmakervx.net/index.php?showforum=38). 
Also in the same forum I found [this](http://www.rpgmakervx.net/index.php?showtopic=57237).

Comment: I'll try what you said.

Comment: This answer would be improved if you'd provide a high-level outline of the technique you need to apply to remove battle scenes; link-only answers are generally considered poor quality and discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. I have made a few games like this; you may even be surprised to learn that RPG Maker can be used to make non-RPG games; see [this blog post](http://blog.rpgmakerweb.com/tips-and-tricks/rpg-maker-horror-games/) on the RPG Maker blog.

Games people have made include:

- Horror
- Adventure
- Interactive fiction
- Shooters

It's really up to you whether you use (or don't use) aspects of the game.

Also, due to the (insane) level of customization, you can also get away with things like disabling/removing menu items (if they're not used for your game).